# What is the keyboard shortcut to enter address bar of Windows Explorer in the German version of Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer, address-bar

I open Windows Explorer mostly by using the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> shortcut. I want to enter the folder directly after Windows-Explorer opened but for that I have to use the mouse, click to the address bar and then I can start typing.

How can I achieve this via the keyboard in Windows 7?

I am aware of a similar [question](https://superuser.com/questions/30246), but the mentioned <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> just opens an item of the menu bar, at least in my Windows 7.

**EDIT**

I am using the german version of Windows 7. The first menu in the menu bar is labeled "Datei" ("File"), which has the "D" underlined .. so it seems to be a menu shortcut. Checking the [german version](http://windows.microsoft.com/de-DE/windows-vista/Keyboard-shortcuts) of the keyboard shortcuts overview for Vista does not list <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, for Windows 7 it is listed, but does not work.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A bit hidden in the "wrong" section ("general" instead of "windows-explorer") of the [documentation](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/Windows7/Keyboard-shortcuts), but as it seems:

<kbd>F4</kbd> - Display the address bar list in Windows Explorer

means "Press F4 and you can start typing in the address bar"

Comment: For me in Windows 8 <kbd>F4</kbd> puts the cursor in the address bar at the end - without selecting all the text. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> puts the cursor in the address bar but selects all the text as well.

Answer (score 10):

The shortcut to the address bar in the German version of Windows 7 is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>

Comment: or just f4 in every version of windows7 :)

Comment: But F4 does not select the text, so you have to press Shift+Home first... so Alt+D / Alt+E is superior

Comment: @ColinDBennett you can press Esc after F4, the text will also be automatically selected

Comment: Works for me, too. The MS documentation is incorrect: http://windows.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/keyboard-shortcuts#keyboard-shortcuts=windows-7
Also see http://superuser.com/questions/185971/keyboard-shortcut-for-the-windows-explorer-address-bar

Comment: Does someone know the shortcut for the French version ? Neither Alt+D, nor Alt+E works.

Answer (score 4):

In **Windows 8**, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (= shortcut to select address bar in Chrome and Firefox)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Start -> Run (Win + R)` and type `explorer foldername`, for example

- `explorer %TEMP%` opens up my temp directory
- `explorer c:\windows` opens the windows folder

Comment: yep, i am aware of that way. but if i have the windows explorer open, that does not help :)