# Keyboard shortcut for the Windows Explorer address bar

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer

Is there a keyboard shortcut in Windows Explorer (Windows 7), to put the cursor into the address bar (where the current path is shown)?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Found it, it's possible with the following two shortcuts:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> selects the current path in English versions (see comments for other languages)
- on Windows 8, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> can also be used to select the current path (all languages)
- <kbd>F4</kbd> will put the cursor at the end of the current path and expand the dropdown list of the address bar (all languages)

BTW: here's a complete list of keyboard shortcuts in windows 7: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: Those shortcuts also work on IE, and ALT+D works on all browsers.

Comment: Alt+D doesn't work on non-English versions of Windows 7 (tried on Brazilian Portuguese and German, probably affects others).

Comment: Alt+D doesn't work in Ukrainian and Russian versions as well.

Comment: [Alt+E works in the German Windows 7](http://superuser.com/a/309293/226237)

Comment: Alt+D works well in Spanish version of Windows 7.

Comment: F4, Esc seems to work on French Windows 7.  So does Ctrl+E, Alt+A

Comment: The link for the shortcuts is broken. [This one works](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts)

Answer (score 5):

If you're using non-English version, you can use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) with this script:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class CabinetWClass
   !d::ControlClick,ToolbarWindow322
return
```

Comment: I went with `^l::` for Control+L.

Comment: For anyone stumbling on this in late 2020 (and possibly later), it should now be `ToolbarWindow323` instead of `ToolbarWindow322`.

Answer (score 3):

Another AutoHotKey solution based on the one from @epifun

@epifun 's solution does not work if the address in the addressbar is very long.

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class CabinetWClass
   !d::
   ControlFocus, ToolbarWindow322
   send {space}
return
```

Comment: For anyone stumbling on this in late 2020 (and possibly later), it should now be `ToolbarWindow323` instead of `ToolbarWindow322`.

Answer (score 2):

I can't verify this myself at the moment since I'm using Mac OS X, but [this webpage](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Keyboard-shortcuts) suggests that `Alt-D` is what you're looking for (see section "Windows Explorer keyboard shortcuts").

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> seems to be working in many browsers, in File Explorer too. It's in Windows 8 (in Windows 7 it does not work).

Comment: That's because in Windows 7 one is still able to reach it by cycling via `F6` between panes, while in Windows 10 you have no chance other than by using `CTRL+L`.

Answer (score -2):

<kbd>F6</kbd> does the trick for me.

(PC, successive versions of Windows including 8.1, as I write.)

Comment: <kbd>F6</kbd> changes focus to the column header for me in Windows 7.

Comment: Windows 8.1 here and F6 doesn't work for me. It seems to select the next Windows pane, similar to pressing Tab. I believe your solution is for Internet Explorer (not Windows Explorer) and other browsers, where F6 does change focus to the Address Bar.

Comment: Have you guys pressed `F6` repeatedly? `Tab` is for controls, `F6` for whole regions/panes - both are relative (as per current focus), not absolute. Try handling programs like _Outlook_ with keyboard alone - then you'll notice how `F6` is intended.