# Select the address bar in Windows Explorer 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keyboard shortcut for the windows explorer address bar](https://superuser.com/questions/185971/keyboard-shortcut-for-the-windows-explorer-address-bar)

In Windows XP's version of Windows Explorer, it was easy to get the folder address. From the document pane I could just hit `Tab` once and the address bar would be highlighted, ready to `Ctrl-C` the address.

This no longer works in Windows 7. How can I copy the address of the current folder without having to use the mouse to click in the address bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, a [good answer](https://superuser.com/a/185972/9350) was linked *after* I posted the question: the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> selects the current path.

Comment: The question and answer were posted in 2010. I see no reason for you to have created this question or your answer above?

Comment: @HaydnWVN When writing a question, possible related topics that might contain the answer are presented, similar to the sidebar on the right. It sounds like the linked topic wasn't presented then, but only afterwards.

Comment: Which means he didn't try searching... Ah well, can't do that *every* time I guess :)

Comment: @HaydnWVN: Thank you but I did search and didn't find it. So I figured this extra post would present an extra (=bigger) target for the search, which is why I also linked to the correct answer. Vote to delete the whole Q&A if you disagree but I felt this made sense.