# Launch CMD here for Dragon NaturallySpeaking

Tags: vbscript, speech-recognition, dragon-naturally-speaking, speech-to-text

I'm a heavy speech recognition user, due to issues with my hands causing much pain. I've been trying to get a command written for Dragon that will launch the Command Prompt in the currently active Windows Explorer window, but can't seem to get it right.

I own the v14 Pro version of Dragon, I also have Vocola / Natlink, and Unimacro installed.

What I have tried so far is creating a custom step by step command that launches command prompt with the start location set to %~dp0

However, that seems to merely launch the cmd with my desktop directory, I'm not sure what's going on there.

I'm not very knowledgeable in the realms of VBScripting, so I've not tried that, now am I certain how to accomplish it with Vocola. I'll continue doing research on this, but in hoping someone here may be able to shorten my search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you create a step-by-step command that does this in Windows Explorer:

1. Press  <kbd>Alt-d</kbd>  (to go to the Address Bar). Your shortcut may be different depending on the language or version of Windows ([Keyboard shortcut for the Windows Explorer address bar](https://superuser.com/questions/185971/keyboard-shortcut-for-the-windows-explorer-address-bar)).  <kbd>Alt-e</kbd>  for German.
2. Type `cmd`, then press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

This will open the Command Prompt in the directory of the current window.

It's a GUI script. It relies on keyboard shortcuts. It profits from the fact that  <kbd>Alt-d</kbd>  will jump to the Address Bar of Windows Explorer.

There may be more elegant, scriptable solutions that rely on identifying the current path from the window title, you may want to ask on a specialized speech recognition forum for someone to help you with that.

(Inspired by this answer on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11244240.)

Comment: Thank you, although, on my computer it is actually alt+d not e. But thank you.

Comment: @user320055 Okay, corrected that. My answer was correct for German. You may accept my answer if it solved your problem. :)

Comment: It certainly does solve the problem, if not in the method is asked, at least it works eh?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the equivalent in advanced scripting that I use:

```
Sub Main
    SendKeys "%d"
    Wait(0.1)
    SendKeys "cmd"
    Wait(0.1)
    SendKeys "{ENTER}"
End Sub
```

[image]