# Windows OS shortcut for window file path

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard-shortcuts, window

Pressing `Windows key` + `E` opens a new window. Then which shortcut keys can be used to go file path in that opened window.

[image].

Comment: You might want to see here: **[What is the keyboard shortcut to enter address bar of Windows Explorer](http://superuser.com/questions/158496/what-is-the-keyboard-shortcut-to-enter-address-bar-of-windows-explorer-in-the-ge)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it, it's possible with the following two shortcuts:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> selects the current path in English
  versions (see comments for other languages)
- On Windows 8, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> can also be used to select the current path (all
  languages)
- <kbd>F4</kbd> will put the cursor at the end of the current path and expand the
  dropdown list of the address bar (all languages)